# fullRefferer data are missing on a very large timerange

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api

We have a very big analytics account with a lot of referal traffic.

We do the following API Queries to get fullRefferer with Session count for the last 30 days and the whole timeframe:

https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=xxx&start-date=30daysAgo&end-date=today&metrics=ga%3Asessions&dimensions=ga%3AfullReferrer&sort=-ga%3Asessions&samplingLevel=HIGHER_PRECISION&max-results=10000

https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=xxx&start-date=2005-01-01&end-date=today&metrics=ga%3Asessions&dimensions=ga%3AfullReferrer&sort=-ga%3Asessions&samplingLevel=HIGHER_PRECISION&max-results=10000

Especially the whole timeframe query takes a lot of time (what is clear). The strange thing happens is that there are referal URLs inside the 30DaysAgo Results ... but not inside the 2005-01-01 Results. This is very unlogical :).

does anyone has some ideas why those data are missing? maybe google dont deliver all referrers when there is a big timeframe?

thank you very much,
Bastian

Answer (score 0):

[How sampling works](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192?hl=en)

> Sampling in Analytics is the practice of selecting a subset of data
>   from your traffic and reporting on the trends available in that sample
>   set. Sampling is widely used in statistical analysis because analyzing
>   a subset of data gives similar results to analyzing all of the data.
>   In addition, sampling speeds up processing for reports when the volume
>   of data is so large as to slow down report queries.

When sampling is applied

> Specifically, Analytics inspects the number of sessions for the
>   specified date range at the property level. If the number of sessions
>   in the property over the given date range exceeds 250k sessions (25M
>   for Premium)1, Analytics will employ a sampling algorithm which uses a
>   sample set proportional to the distribution of sessions by day for the
>   selected date range. Thus, the session sampling rate varies for every
>   query depending on the number of sessions included in the selected
>   date range for the given property.

You cant prevent sampling.

> HIGHER_PRECISION — Returns a more accurate response using a large
>   sample size, but this may result in the response being slower.

Check your response it will tell you if the data is sampled

Comment: thank you very much. as you can see in our query, we already use HIGHER_PRECISION ... but i will check the response if sampling was used.

Comment: That's what gave me the idea as to what your problem can be.

Comment: Hi Theo,

This are some insights about sampling:

getSampleSize() => string(6) "689833"
getSampleSpace() => string(8) "30007290"
getContainsSampledData() => bool(true)

What we already do is using pagination. We only get 5000 results per page. The dimension i cannot reduce, because we need the given dimensions to get the data. The only thing we could optimize is the datarange ... but when i split the datarange into weeks for example ... we will do a lot of APi requests which will take a while but the single request should be faster as the while daterange.

what would you recommend?

Comment: Reducing the number of results per page will not effect sampling it's based upon the total result set. This is why I normally fetch data at one to three day steps.

Comment: As long as you don't exceed the 10000 request per view per day quota it shouldn't be a problem. Remember this is old data store it you need only request it once

Comment: I understand! What if i filter only for a specific URL, i want to receive the session count for a long timeframe. will they also sample?

So the workflow could be, that for the past traffic, i will do a specific API request with only dimension session and one filter:

https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=xxx&start-date=2005-01-01&end-date=today&metrics=ga%3Asessions&sort=-ga%3Asessions&filters=ga%3AfullReferrer%3D%3Dsomeurl.de&samplingLevel=HIGHER_PRECISION&max-results=10000

and afterwards i will add the new traffic always to the total amount.

Comment: It depends on the amount of data " If the number of sessions in the property over the given date range exceeds 250k sessions "

Comment: also switch to v4 of the api.   Improvements to the quota system will likely appear there instead of V3

Comment: i dont think so, because it is referal traffic. thank you so far

Comment: I also checked if i can pass the URLs inside the filters where i want to have the session count. but this query is also not good, because they go through each row and use the filters ....

the problem is that the website has a massive amount of referals .... even when i set ga:medium == referral and i only select 6 months ... i get over 500k different referral urls.

when i want to do this now for alltime (starting from 2005) it is endless :(.

maybe it helps you when i tell you what i need:

i have 10000 referral urls and i want to have the sessions.

how would you do this?